# Is there a way to enter a number through another number?

Tags: c++

I'm taking a C++ class in school, (No experience with programming) so I realize that this is a very dumb question and also horribly worded but here it is:

Is there any way to enter 6-21 (As in 6 through 21) into a boolean expression? I've tried it like this:

if (regs = 6-21)

But it assumes that I'm trying to subtract. What I'm trying to ask is, is there a way to enter a number through another number? Is it even possible?

Comment: You mean `6 <= regs && regs <= 21`?

Comment: Pretty sure there's a typo above and  `6 >= regs && regs <= 21` was intended.

Comment: @user4581301 no, what Mike showed is correct. https://ideone.com/HsfyxE

Comment: @user4581301 you've found a convoluted way of writing `regs <= 6`

Comment: The fiend swapped around where `reg` was.  Perfect example of paying too much attention to the operator and not enough to the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do it:

```cpp
if (regs >= 6 && regs <= 21) {
  // some code
}
```

`>=` means "greater than or equal to".
`<=` means "less than or equal to".
`&&` means "and", as in "if this AND this is true".

Comment: I'd recommend more readable `6 <= regs && regs <= 21)`

Comment: @Superior I disagree that it's any more readable.

Comment: it's more like in math `6 ≤ regs ≤ 21`

Comment: @Sup I could argue that, if you spell it out in English, it's "if regs is greater than or equal to 6 and less than or equal to 21", so mine is more Enlgish-like (hence more readable). But neither is more readable and I doubt anyone is going to have problems with either.

Comment: `6 <= regs && regs <= 21` is more readable in my opinion because it places `regs` between `6` and `21`, which is the arithmetic relationship it's intending to express. If you were reading it out loud, you wouldn't say "six is less than or equal to regs and regs is less than or equal to twenty-one" or "regs is greater than equal to six and regs is less than or equal to 21", probably, you'd say "between".

Comment: @Nathan until C++ has a "between" operator, I am going to read it the way I showed :-). This is bikeshedding at this point, I am sure any readers of this post will be able to decide what convention they want to follow after understanding the syntax.